# Set up NSNotification when camera is actually showing on view

Tags: ios, swift, camera, nsnotificationcenter

I am using an augmented reality framework that sets up several things before running the device's camera, at which point, I would like to hide a loading view in the view controller.

However, I am not sure which notification advices on the camera view actually showing on the view.

So far I am using:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.camActive), name: NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunning, object: nil)
```

but it is being called before the camera output shows on my view, and while my system is still loading AR elements.

Am I calling the wrong notification, or is there a more effective way to achieve my goal of hiding the view one the camera is actually active?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to show the image view after the AR stuff are loaded?

Comment: I want to hide a UIView once the camera appears.